# The class 'FirebaseAnalytics' doesn't have an unnamed constructor

Tags: flutter, firebase-analytics

I would like to use firebase analytics but keep getting this error, I upgrade and cleaned but still has the same error. any idea how I can solve it? thanks

`static FirebaseAnalytics analytics = FirebaseAnalytics();` **FirebaseAnalytics** is underlined

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I solve it by removing the parentheses and adding `.instance`.

`static FirebaseAnalytics analytics = FirebaseAnalytics.instance;`

see [documentation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/analytics/get-started). Thanks